# Yeoman - Can't install generators

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

I can't install generators using Yeoman.

Not sure how to resolve this, using OSX Yosemite.

> npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0 npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
>   "install" "-g" "generator-aspnet" npm ERR! node v0.12.0 npm ERR! npm 
>   v2.5.1 npm ERR! path
>   /Users/briandouglas/.node/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet npm ERR!
>   code EACCES npm ERR! errno -13
>
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink
>   '/Users/briandouglas/.node/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet' npm ERR!
>   at Error (native) npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink
>   '/Users/briandouglas/.node/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet'] npm
>   ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   path:
>   '/Users/briandouglas/.node/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet' } npm
>   ERR! npm ERR! Please try running this command again as
>   root/Administrator. npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink
>   '/Users/briandouglas/.node/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet' npm ERR!
>   error rolling back     at Error (native) npm ERR! error rolling back 
>   { [Error: EACCES, unlink
>   '/Users/briandouglas/.node/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet'] npm
>   ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13, npm ERR! error rolling back
>   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR! error rolling back   path:
>   '/Users/briandouglas/.node/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet' }
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/briandouglas/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that you don't have permission to make the requested modifications.

Perhaps at some point in the past you've run `npm` as `sudo npm ...`, which would have run it as root and written files in such a way that your user may not be permitted to change them.  Only the files written at that time would have been affected.

Try running `chown -R briandouglas ~/.node` and then trying to install the generator again.

Answer (score 0):

If changing permissions doesn´t solve your problem. Try uninstalling modules installed as root `sudo npm uninstall -g ***` and installing again not as sudo. this should be enough.